# how to change format of a date string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, tostring

I have a date string like "30/01/2018"
and I want a format like "2018/01/30"

I have tried the following lines,

```
DateTime.Parse(startDate.Text.ToString()).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

and

`DateTime.ParseExact(startDate.Text.ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

but didn't work.
Anyother solution?

Comment: what you have in `startDate.Text`

Comment: Your code uses the default locale of your server or client machine where it executes. If the locale cannot understand the format of your strings it cannot convert to a proper datetime value. What is the locale where this code runs? (By the way, Text is already a string property, no sense in calling ToString on it)

Comment: are you passing it to a new variable?

Comment: Also there is no overload of ParseExact with only two arguments, the same for the first example. Both don't compile if you don't add a CultureInfo parameter

Comment: startDate.Text = "30/01/2018" @un-lucky

Comment: I am parsing it and saving it in a new string @ninja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this

```
string newFormat = DateTime.ParseExact("30/01/2018", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want output in string. Why not split and re-arrange?

```
string strOldFormat = "30/01/2018";
string[] strArrOldFormat = strOldFormat.Split('/');
string strNewFormat = strArrOldFormat[2] + "/" + strArrOldFormat[1] + "/" + strArrOldFormat[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape your slashes (and use a Culture with `ParseExact`)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("30/01/2018","dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd")
```

Or use the `InvariantCulture` for the `ToString` instead of escaping the slash:

```
...ToString(@"yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Reason is, that `/` is a special format character for dates:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings - The "/" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified culture.

Comment: it is the backslash character that needs to be escaped not the forward slash.

Comment: @Steve does the edit answer your concerns? And backslash doesn't need escape with `@"string"`

Comment: you don't need to escape it. Just use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in `ToString()` method and you don't have to worry about culture's date separator.

Comment: @grek40 as you don't need the verbatim character before the first dd/MM/yyyy you don't need it and the backslash before the second

Comment: @Nino yes, I already mentioned this as a second option... but still it's equally valid to escape a special character in order to use it literally :)

Comment: @grek40, ok, you're right, but I would define that as overengineering.

Answer (score 2):

Try using below sample code:-

```
var  actualStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate.Text.ToString(),"yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
string dateString = startDate.Text.ToString();
string format="yyyy/MM/dd"; 
string result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider).ToString();
```

or You can bundle it into one line like this

```
string result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(startDate.Text.ToString(),"yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTimeOffset_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Comment: more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTimeOffset_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_

Answer (score 1):

You can use this;

```
String.Format("{0: yyyy/MM/dd}", yourDate);
```